# Use Mask-RCNN or Unet for calculating angle of multiple seedling

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning

Hello i'm currently working on a project where i have to use instance segmentation of  different parts of seedlings (the top part and the stem)
Example image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG8fG.jpg
I have to be able to calculate the angle of the hook for every seedling.

I've heard that the Mask-RCNN instance segmentation method might not be good for biological images, so should i go with  U-net semantic segmentation instead?. The problem with U-net is that every seed and root gets categorized into two classes, where as i need to calculate the angle for each of them.

Some input would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you could clarify why you can't calculate the angle between them, "when every seed and root gets categorized into two classes"?

Comment: As some seeds that are close together may be categorized as one root/seed, but i might get past that. Do you think that i should go for U-Net ?

Comment: I would use U-Net for other reasons as well. accuracy and speed... but, Frankly, you should start with whichever network is easiest for you to get off the ground and see if it's good enough. If not, try another model and see if it's good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with whichever network is easiest for you to get off the ground and see if it's good enough. If not, try another model and see if it's good enough.

You can only go so far in choosing a network architecture for a new image use case. Sometimes you just have to try a few on the new type of image data and see which performs best.

Because your time is valuable, I would recommend starting with the simplest/fastest model for you to use, and try a "trickier" one, only if the first one wasn't good enough.

I must add that it's kind of difficult to understand all of the nuance's of your requirements just from the one image you posted...

good luck.